# Thunderbird uses wrong attachment mime type on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, thunderbird, attachments, mime-types

Thunderbird running on Windows Vista has usually sent Microsoft Word documents as mime type `application/msword`, which as I understand is correct. However, now it has suddenly decided to send Word documents as mime type `text/richtext`, which creates a big problem as a recipient client may interpret the message as displayable inline - which in fact just creates garbage on the screen as it cannot handle direct display of Word documents. At least Thunderbird itself as a recipient does this, but I'd imagine other clients might as well.

As far as I can understand, Thunderbird picks up the mime type of the attachment from the operating system, instead of determining it by itself. This would suggest that something might be wrong with how Vista assigns mime types. <strike>However, I coudn't find a way to adjust on Vista how mime types are determined - only file type setting seems to be about which program opens them.</strike> However, this seems to be in order, since in registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc` does contain the correct mime type - and in fact, the string `text/richtext` is nowhere to be found in registry.

It's also worth mentioning that other file types do still get their correct mime type.

**How do I force Thunderbird to use the correct `application/msword` mime type for Microsoft Word document attachments (when sending email)?**

<strike>Or: How do I determine what mime types are assigned to different file types on Windows Vista?</strike>

Or: **How do I troubleshoot this issue further?** (For example by determining if the problem is with Vista providing the wrong mime type for Thunderbird, or with Thunderbird not accepting what vista provides?)

Here's a sample of the failed attachment header:

```
Content-Type: text/richtext; name="Foo Bar.doc"    
Content-Description: Foo Bar.doc    
Content-Disposition: attachment;    
 filename="Foo Bar.doc"; size=85056;    
 creation-date="Thu, 17 Sep 2009 11:14:20 GMT";    
 modification-date="Thu, 17 Sep 2009 11:14:20 GMT"    
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

---

**The problem now has a solution.** The immediate cause of the problem turned out to be `mimeTypes.rdf`. The problem was caused by (and can be duplicated by adding) the following section in the file:

```
<RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:mimetypes:root">
  <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:text/richtext"/>
</RDF:Seq>
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:text/richtext"
                 NC:value="text/richtext"
                 NC:editable="true"
                 NC:fileExtensions="doc"
                 NC:description="Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003">
  <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:text/richtext"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Thunderbird/Firefox do use a sophisticated mime type related machinery independent from the operating system (OS). Consequently I would think that your issue is not *caused* by the OS (hence might not be specific to Vista, or even Windows), though the OS mime type settings might still *influence* initial handling of attachments once Thunderbird/Firefox encounter a mime type for the first time. See my answer too (http://superuser.com/questions/42545/thunderbird-uses-wrong-attachment-mime-type-on-windows-vista/46107#46107).

Comment: Are things different when you send plain-text messages with Word attachments (compared to sending Rich Text/HTML messages, with the very same attachments)? (And if things are different: maybe you changed the way you compose messages?)

Comment: @Arjan: Switching between HTML/plaintext modes and back did not affect the problem.

Comment: @Ilari: thanks much for the detailed follow ups to your question as well as my answer - highly appreciated by everyone encountering this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting issue. Upfront it's worth noting that [`text/richtext`](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1896.txt) is an e-mail related mime type obsoleted by [`text/enriched`](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1896.txt) and entirely unrelated to [`application/rtf`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/rtf), see Wikipedia about [Enriched text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_text):

> Enriched text is a formatted text
> format for e-mail, defined by the IETF
> in [RFC 1896](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1896) and associated with the
> text/enriched MIME type.
> [...]
> A predecessor of this `text/enriched` MIME type was called `text/richtext` in [RFC 1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341) and [RFC 1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521). Neither should be confused with [Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (MIME type `text/rtf` or `application/rtf`) which is an entirely different specification, devised by Microsoft.

The only clue I could find is targeting Horde/IMP via Firefox, but seems to address the same problem, see [Word attachment file problem](http://groups.google.com/group/mailing.www.horde-imp/browse_thread/thread/e1439dc1e52464bc):

> You might have received some document
> which is in rich text format.   You
> might have opened it using Microsoft
> word and this has resulted in   adding
> a mime-type called 'text/richtext'
> with its supporting   application as
> MS-word in your browser setting.
> Subsequently, when   you attach any
> word document, the browser is
> identifying any attached   word
> document as 'text/richtext' type
> instead of 'application/msword'.

Due to Firefox and Thunderbird sharing much code this might well apply to Thunderbird too.

> How do I force Thunderbird to use the
> correct application/msword mime type
> for Microsoft Word document
> attachments (when sending email)?

Why this is happening has apparently not been finally resolved, however, the temporary solution offered by the poster should apply too, as Thunderbird is using `mimeTypes.rdf` also. However, **before** applying the drastic measure to simply delete this file from your Thunderbird user profile and restart Thunderbird (which will likely restore the default file), I'd try to investigate this further to avoid loosing deliberate changes to `Download Actions`:

- First you should have a look into your
  Thunderbird settings:
  Under `Tools->Options->Attachments->Download Actions` you'll
  find the user configured mime type
  related actions per file extension as stored in
  `mimeTypes.rdf` (i.e. just those different
  from default settings I guess). In
  principle the changed setting
  regarding Word documents should
  manifest itself there (though given the circumstances it might as well be some implied specialty or even a bug).
- In case this doesn't yield a result you could still peak into
  `mimeTypes.rdf` and try to figure out
  which particular setting is wrong, if
  any.

Whether avoiding the simple deletion of `mimetypes.rdf` like so is worth the trouble depends on your situation of course.

Comment: Even more confusing: there's also text/rtf which according to Wikipedia is for Microsoft's RTF. However, http://www.fileformat.info/info/mimetype/text/rtf refers to something different than the RTF as mentioned in http://www.fileformat.info/info/mimetype/application/rtf

Comment: The culprit here was the mimeTypes.rdf. It contained a definition for `text/richtext` that associated with the file extension `doc`. **Deleting the file (or poking around with it) fixed the problem!** Of course, out of curiosity, I would *love* to know what exactly had happened to it, what was the cause here - but the main thing is that Thunderbird is again working as it should.

Comment: For the record, "Download Actions" was empty, and adding an association to `DOC` there did not affect the issue.

Comment: For the record, I'm *not* able to duplicate the sending problem by simply opening a `doc` attachment which I've intentionally sent with wrong header `text/richtext`. However if I tell Thunderbird to "always perform this action" when I open the file, this *does* cause Thunderbird to use the the same wrong mime type when sending `doc` files. However, this condition is fixable by simple removing the bad entry from `Tools->Options->Attachments->Download Actions`, as described - in my initial problem the list was empty.

Comment: @Arjan: thanks much for updating Wikipedia and my answer in turn - I stumbled myself at first read, your edits removed the possible confusion!

Answer (score 1):

I think Thunderbird should just use the Windows MIME type associations. Is it possible some antisocial program has scribbled over the associations for .doc?

I'm not sure it's possible to see the MIME type associations in the UI in Vista, but the information should still be there in the registry. Check the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc` in regedit and see what the ‘Content Type’ value on the right is.

Comment: Ah, ok. `regedit` is UI enough. :) But no, `.doc` was set correctly to `application/msword`, as was even `.rtf`. And in fact the string `text/richtext` was not found anywhere on registry! So it's looking more like a Thunderbird problem, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

I suppoert Ilari's view that this is not a Windows registry problem, as I encounter it on linux, too (Xubuntu 9.10; Thunderbird 2.0.0.23). Here, too, the line in mimeTypes.rdf that links .doc to text/richtext has to be deleted, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Even Thunderbird 17.0.2 has a `mimetypes.rdf`-problem. As in my case it can't and won't start the proper application `textmaker.exe` for my `*.tmd`-attachments. A guy named hooks prompted a very well working workaround in a softmaker-forum.

This workaround runs perfectly on Windows 7 Ultimate and Vista Home.

The workaround [comes with this addon](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/OpenAttachmentByExtension-0.3.5.1.xpi).

Install it, configure it, work with it!